# Why is BeautifulSoup leaving out parts of a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm completely new to python and wanted to dip my toes into web scraping. So I tried to scrape the rankings of players in https://www.fencingtimelive.com/events/competitors/F87F9E882BD6467FB9461F68E484B8B3# 
But when I try to access the rankings and ratings of each player, it gives none as a return. This is all inside the  so I assume beautifulsoup isn't able to access it because it's javascript, but I'm not sure. please help ._.

Input:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


URL_USAFencingOctoberNac_2022 = "https://www.fencingtimelive.com/events/competitors/F87F9E882BD6467FB9461F68E484B8B3"
October_Nac_2022 = requests.get(URL_USAFencingOctoberNac_2022)
October_Nac_2022 = BeautifulSoup(October_Nac_2022.text, "html.parser")


tbody = October_Nac_2022.tbody
print(tbody)
```

Output:

```
None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the problem is not with `BS4`  but with your analysis before starting the scraping. The data which you are looking for is not available directly from the request you have made.

To get the data you have to make request to a different back end URL `https://www.fencingtimelive.com/events/competitors/data/F87F9E882BD6467FB9461F68E484B8B3?sort=name`, which will give you a JSON response.

The code will look something like this

```
from requests import get
url = 'https://www.fencingtimelive.com/events/competitors/data/F87F9E882BD6467FB9461F68E484B8B3?sort=
name'
response = get(url, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0 X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest'})
print(response.json())
```

If you want to test performance of BS4 consider the below example for fetching the blog post links from the [link](https://www.zyte.com/blog/)

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = "https://www.zyte.com/blog/"
response = get(url, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux soup = bs(response.content)
posts = soup.find_all('div', {"class":"oxy-posts"})
print(len(posts))
```

Note:
Before writing code for scraping analyse the website thoroughly. It will give the idea about the data sources of the website